# Add a class to a Shopify liquid link?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to generate a log out link for my customers but want to apply a class to the link.

```
{{ 'layout.customer.log_out' | t | customer_logout_link }}
```

The above liquid code generates

```
<a href="/account/logout" id="customer_logout_link">Log out</a>
```

I would like to add a class attribute. For example,

```
<a href="/account/logout" class="CLASS-NAME" id="customer_logout_link">Log out</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add class directly to the link filter, but you can add your own link.

So the following code `{{ 'layout.customer.log_out' | t | customer_logout_link }}` will be converted to.

`<a href="/account/logout" id="customer_logout_link">{{ 'layout.customer.log_out' | t }}</a>`

And you can add what ever class you like.

The filter `customer_logout_link` is just a shorthand to write the standard link. If you plan to use anything outside the standard HTML structure of the button just write it down as a standard html link.

Answer (score 10):

You can add class to link using `replace` filter, your code will look like this

```
{{ 'layout.customer.log_out' | t | customer_logout_link | replace: '<a', '<a class="my_class"' }}
```

Comment: I'd rather go with this than the solution because styling with a class is better than an id

Comment: This is the better answer because you want those links to be dynamic. Otherwise why use liquid tags at all?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fully liquid solution:

```
{{ 'layout.customer.log_out' | t | customer_logout_link, class: "CLASS-NAME" }}
```

I have not seen this mentioned anywhere in the Shopify documentation though.

Answer (score 0):

For the best of both worlds, you can still utilize the dynamic url and break this out into your own html by adding the `route` in liquid as the `href`. [See Shopify documentation on routes](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/routes)

```
<a href="{{ routes.account_logout_url }}" class="my_class" >
  {{ 'layout.customer.log_out' | t }}
</a>
```