# What is the shortcode to pull the account page urls through without the anchor tags?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shortcode

I am building a theme and require the links to the log in / log out / register pages but don't want the classic shortcode. I simply want the URL nothing else.

How are these urls called without the anchor tags?

Classic shortcode:

```
{% if shop.customer_accounts_enabled %}
    {% if customer %}
        <a href="/account">My Account</a>
        {{ 'Log Out' | customer_logout_link }}
    {% else %}
        {{ 'Log In ' | customer_login_link }}
        {{ 'Register' | customer_register_link }}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Required format:

```
{{ customer_logout_link_url }}
{{ customer_login_link_url }}
{{ customer_register_link_url }}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this isn't possible. The [docs](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/url-filters#customer_login_link) don't offer a way to do it.

Depending on why you want to do this, though, there is an alternative. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48591368/945370) shows how you can add custom classes to the generated link, if that's what you need to do. A simpler version of it looks like:

```
{{ "Log Me Out!" | customer_logout_link | replace: '<a', '<a class="button button--primary"' }}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can capture whatever is echoed as a link, then use that variable instead:

```
{% capture customer_logout_link_url %}{{ 'Log Out' | customer_logout_link }}{% endcapture %}
{% capture customer_login_link_url %}{{ 'Log In ' | customer_login_link }}{% endcapture %}
{% capture customer_register_link_url %}{{ 'Register' | customer_register_link }}{% endcapture %}

{% if shop.customer_accounts_enabled %}
    {% if customer %}
        <a href="/account">My Account</a>
        {{ customer_logout_link_url }}
    {% else %}
        {{ customer_login_link_url }}
        {{ customer_register_link_url }}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```